# get row with max from group by results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have sql such as:

```
select 
  c.customerID, sum(o.orderCost) 
from customer c, order o 
where c.customerID=o.customerID 
group by c.customerID;
```

This returns a list of

```
customerID, orderCost
```

where `orderCost` is the total cost of all orders the customer has made. I want to select the customer who has paid us the most (who has the highest orderCost). Do I need to create a nested query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create nested query for this.
Two queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested query, but you don't have to access the tables twice if you use [analytic functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions004.htm#i81407).

```
select customerID, sumOrderCost from
(
    select customerID, sumOrderCost,
        rank() over (order by sumOrderCost desc) as rn
    from (
        select c.customerID, sum(o.orderCost) as sumOrderCost
        from customer c, orders o
        where c.customerID=o.customerID
        group by c.customerID
    )
)
where rn = 1;
```

The `rank()` function ranks the results from your original query by the `sum()` value, then you only pick those with the highest rank - that is, the row(s) with the highest total order cost.

If more than one customer has the same total order cost, this will return both. If that isn't what you want you'll have to decide how to determine which single result to use. If you want the lowest customer ID, for example, add that to the ranking function:

```
select customerID, sumOrderCost,
    rank() over (order by sumOrderCost desc, customerID) as rn
```

You can adjust you original query to return other data instead, just for the ordering, and not include it in the outer `select`.